# Got base64 encoded text when retrieved email from pop3 protocol in terminal

Tags: networking, terminal, openssl, base64, pop3

I created a  pop3 protocol connection to my Gmail server using **OpenSSL on terminal**, just for testing and learning purposes, I used **retr {no}** command to retrieve my email data, **but the data is encoded in base64**.

How can I decode my email data from base64 to text while retrieving the mail or after retrieving it?

Here are the commands I used to connect to the server and use pop3 protocol using Openssl:-

```
openssl s_client -connect pop.gmail.com:995 -quiet
```

```
user <USERNAME>
pass <PASSWORD>
```

**NOTE** :- The password should be the app password of your gmail

```
list
```

**NOTE** :- to list all the mails inside the server

```
retr 1
```

> Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"; format=flowed; delsp=yes
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

> R29vZ2xlICANCjxodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29tL2FwcHNlcnZlL21rdC9wL0FGbnduS1Vx
> WkdQbUdFLTAxcVBRcDdkTUhHa3lZRnd3WnNBV3VZQjFmLTVWUHdhTXFQRGtTTjAwMDFKQVFCZ255
> STI3YW9UbGswb2FHa2hIdTltMklIUGN0cDFrVGZTQzBNVUZnclVwSlNjN3lLNWE4RGRFZUVhbDdF
> VmZpTU5ObG91NXphOVEtZ3lQZ3VJWU9rd0FoT2sxdzZlUjVNZDBNYmlFMGc+DQoNCkhpIEFjaGlu
> dHlhLA0KDQpXZWxjb21lIHRvIEdvb2dsZS4gWW91ciBuZXcgYWNjb3VudCBjb21lcyB3aXRoIGFj
> Y2VzcyB0byBHb29nbGUgcHJvZHVjdHMsICANCmFwcHMgYW5kIHNlcnZpY2VzLg0KDQpIZXJlJ3Mg
> YSBmZXcgdGlwcyB0byBnZXQgeW91IHN0YXJ0ZWQuDQoNCkdvb2dsZSBHbyAgDQo8aHR0cHM6Ly93...

*some of the encoded email*

```
quit
```

**NOTE** :- to end the POP3 session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have various options:

- `openssl base64 -d`
- `perl -MMIME::Base64 -0777 -ne 'print decode_base64($_)'`
- `python3 -c 'import sys, base64; sys.stdout.buffer.write(base64.b64decode(sys.stdin.buffer.read()))'`

They all decode Base64 from standard input to standard output.